# Why only first of two jquery files loaded is running?

Tags: javascript

In my theme **Basic**, I'm loading 2 jquery files. Both two are loaded at front page, but only first loaded run. If I change loading order, again only first file do anything.
Here are the examples:

1)
Drupal.behaviors.basic = {
...some jquery stuff...

2)
Drupal.behaviors.basic = {
...some other jquery stuff...

Comment: Hi @Pierre.Vriens, I'm sorry... I have not a copy of the linked files... Just editing the question, a really rockie question... Fell free to ask me for deleting it, if you think it is not very useful... I haven't done if because I think the answer could be useful for someone over there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have the same name, both "basic". Rename one of the 2 and you should be fine.
Change

```
Drupal.behaviors.basic = {
```

To for example

```
Drupal.behaviors.modifications = {
```

The name should be something descriptive about what the underlying functions do.